# A slow sql statments , is there any way to optmize it?

Tags: postgresql

Our application has a very slow statement, it takes more than 11 second, so I want to know is there any way to optimize it ?

**The SQL statement**

```
SELECT id FROM mapfriends.cell_forum_topic WHERE id in   (
SELECT topicid FROM mapfriends.cell_forum_item WHERE skyid=103230293 GROUP BY topicid ) 
AND categoryid=29 AND hidden=false   ORDER BY restoretime DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;

   id    
---------
 2471959
 2382296
 1535967
 2432006
 2367281
 2159706
 1501759
 1549304
 2179763
 1598043
(10 rows)

Time: 11444.976 ms
```

**Plan**

```
friends=> explain SELECT id FROM friends.cell_forum_topic WHERE id in   (
friends(> SELECT topicid FROM friends.cell_forum_item WHERE skyid=103230293 GROUP BY topicid) 
friends-> AND categoryid=29 AND hidden=false   ORDER BY restoretime DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
                                                          QUERY PLAN                                                           
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=1443.15..1443.15 rows=2 width=12)
   ->  Sort  (cost=1443.15..1443.15 rows=2 width=12)
         Sort Key: cell_forum_topic.restoretime
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1434.28..1443.14 rows=2 width=12)
               ->  HashAggregate  (cost=1434.28..1434.30 rows=2 width=4)
                     ->  Index Scan using cell_forum_item_idx_skyid on cell_forum_item  (cost=0.00..1430.49 rows=1516 width=4)
                           Index Cond: (skyid = 103230293)
               ->  Index Scan using cell_forum_topic_pkey on cell_forum_topic  (cost=0.00..4.40 rows=1 width=12)
                     Index Cond: (cell_forum_topic.id = cell_forum_item.topicid)
                     Filter: ((NOT cell_forum_topic.hidden) AND (cell_forum_topic.categoryid = 29))
(10 rows)

Time: 1.109 ms
```

**Indexes**

```
friends=> \d cell_forum_item
                                   Table "friends.cell_forum_item"
 Column  |              Type              |                          Modifiers                           
---------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------
 id      | integer                        | not null default nextval('cell_forum_item_id_seq'::regclass)
 topicid | integer                        | not null
 skyid   | integer                        | not null
 content | character varying(200)         | 
 addtime | timestamp(0) without time zone | default now()
 ischeck | boolean                        | 
Indexes:
    "cell_forum_item_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "cell_forum_item_idx" btree (topicid, skyid)
    "cell_forum_item_idx_1" btree (topicid, id)
    "cell_forum_item_idx_skyid" btree (skyid)
friends=> \d cell_forum_topic
                                                 Table "friends.cell_forum_topic"
   Column    |              Type              |                                      Modifiers                                      

-------------+--------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-
 id          | integer                        | not null default nextval(('"friends"."cell_forum_topic_id_seq"'::text)::regclass)
 categoryid  | integer                        | not null
 topic       | character varying              | not null
 content     | character varying              | not null
 skyid       | integer                        | not null
 addtime     | timestamp(0) without time zone | default now()
 reference   | integer                        | default 0
 restore     | integer                        | default 0
 restoretime | timestamp(0) without time zone | default now()
 locked      | boolean                        | default false
 settop      | boolean                        | default false
 hidden      | boolean                        | default false
 feature     | boolean                        | default false
 picid       | integer                        | default 29249
 managerid   | integer                        | 
 imageid     | integer                        | default 0
 pass        | boolean                        | default false
 ischeck     | boolean                        | 
Indexes:
    "cell_forum_topic_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "idx_cell_forum_topic_1" btree (categoryid, settop, hidden, restoretime, skyid)
    "idx_cell_forum_topic_2" btree (categoryid, hidden, restoretime, skyid)
    "idx_cell_forum_topic_3" btree (categoryid, hidden, restoretime)
    "idx_cell_forum_topic_4" btree (categoryid, hidden, restore)
    "idx_cell_forum_topic_5" btree (categoryid, hidden, restoretime, feature)
    "idx_cell_forum_topic_6" btree (categoryid, settop, hidden, restoretime)
```

**Explain analyze**

```
mapfriends=> explain analyze SELECT id FROM mapfriends.cell_forum_topic 
mapfriends->   join (SELECT topicid FROM mapfriends.cell_forum_item WHERE     skyid=103230293 GROUP BY topicid) as tmp
mapfriends->  on mapfriends.cell_forum_topic.id=tmp.topicid
mapfriends->   where categoryid=29 AND hidden=false ORDER BY restoretime  DESC   LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
                                                                                    QUERY PLAN                                      

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=1446.89..1446.90 rows=2 width=12) (actual time=18016.006..18016.013 rows=10 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=1446.89..1446.90 rows=2 width=12) (actual time=18016.001..18016.002 rows=10 loops=1)
         Sort Key: cell_forum_topic.restoretime
         Sort Method:  quicksort  Memory: 25kB
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1438.02..1446.88 rows=2 width=12) (actual time=16988.492..18015.869 rows=20 loops=1)
               ->  HashAggregate  (cost=1438.02..1438.04 rows=2 width=4) (actual time=15446.735..15447.243 rows=610 loops=1)
                     ->  Index Scan using cell_forum_item_idx_skyid on cell_forum_item  (cost=0.00..1434.22 rows=1520 width=4) (actual time=302.378..15429.782 rows=7133 loops=1)
                           Index Cond: (skyid = 103230293)
               ->  Index Scan using cell_forum_topic_pkey on cell_forum_topic  (cost=0.00..4.40 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=4.210..4.210 rows=0 loops=610)
                     Index Cond: (cell_forum_topic.id = cell_forum_item.topicid)
                     Filter: ((NOT cell_forum_topic.hidden) AND (cell_forum_topic.categoryid = 29))
 Total runtime: 18019.461 ms
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you give us some more information about the tables (the statistics) and the configuration?

```
SELECT version();
SELECT category, name, setting FROM pg_settings WHERE name IN('effective_cache_size', 'enable_seqscan', 'shared_buffers');
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_user_tables WHERE relname IN('cell_forum_topic', 'cell_forum_item');
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_user_indexes WHERE relname IN('cell_forum_topic', 'cell_forum_item');
SELECT * FROM pg_stats WHERE tablename IN('cell_forum_topic', 'cell_forum_item');
```

And before getting this data, use ANALYZE.

It looks like you have a problem with an index, this is where all the query spends all it's time:

> ->  Index Scan using cell_forum_item_idx_skyid on
>   cell_forum_item  (cost=0.00..1434.22
>   rows=1520 width=4) (actual
>   time=302.378..15429.782 rows=7133
>   loops=1)

If you use VACUUM FULL on a regular basis (NOT RECOMMENDED!), index bloat might be your problem. A REINDEX might be a good idea, just to be sure:

```
REINDEX TABLE cell_forum_item;
```

And talking about indexes, you can drop a couple of them, these are obsolete:

```
"idx_cell_forum_topic_6" btree (categoryid, settop, hidden, restoretime)
"idx_cell_forum_topic_3" btree (categoryid, hidden, restoretime)
```

Other indexes have the same data and can be used by the database as well.

---

It looks like you have a couple of problems:

- autovacuum is turned off or it's way
  behind. That last autovacuum was on
  2010-12-02 and you have 256734 dead
  tuples in one table and 451430 dead
  ones in the other.... You have to do
  something about this, this is a
  serious problem.
- When autovacuum is working again, you
  have to do a VACUUM FULL and a
  REINDEX to force a table rewrite and
  get rid of all empty space in your
  tables.
- after fixing the vacuum-problem, you
  have to analyze as well: the database
  expects 1520 results but it gets 7133
  results. This could be a problem with
  statistics, maybe you have to
  increase the [STATISTICS](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html).
- The query itself needs some rewriting
  as well: It gets 7133 results but it
  needs only 610 results. Over 90% of
  the results are lost... And getting
  these 7133 takes a lot of time, over
  15 seconds. Get rid of the subquery by using a JOIN without the GROUP BY or use EXISTS, also without the GROUP BY.

But first get autovacuum back on track, before you get new or other problems.

Comment: Thanks for replying the issue , the following is the detail information.

Comment: Hi: thanks for answering the problem,

1 first about the autovacuum: I am sure that autovacuum have benn turned on,the following is the detail;  
  
mapfriends=> show autovacuum;
 autovacuum 
------------
 on
(1 row)  
  
postgres@db> ps -ef | grep auto
postgres 23011 23006  0 Nov16 ?        00:00:01 postgres: autovacuum launcher process   

2 second about the statistic; Should I analyze the table regulary?
 I turn the prameter autovacuum on ,I think the autovacuum backend process will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

the problem isn't due to lack of caching of the query plan but most likely due to the choice of plan due to lack of appropriate indexes

Comment: From the plan, we can see it uses the right index, and when I use explain analyze , i notice that actual rows is much biger;